# Please explain the output of this JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

```
(function () {
    try {
        throw new Error();
    } catch (x) {
        var x = 1, y = 2;
        console.log(x);
    }
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
})();
```

The output of this code is:

```
1
undefined
2
```

But I am not able to understand how it is. Please explain.

Comment: Which output did you expect instead and why?

Comment: I investigated for a bit and it appears that because you use catch(x) it causes x to be undefined outside of the try-catch statement. It's fixed if you change the catch(x) to catch(e)

Comment: @mkrieger1 my guess is that they expected the second console.log to equal the first one

Comment: ^ This is called shadowing or hiding. It's made extra tricky by throwing in `var` for function-levlel hoisting. This seems more like a puzzle/riddle than a real question.

Comment: This seems like it was written specifically to demonstrate confusing behavior, but as @CollinD says above, the `undefined` is the result of `var x` [being hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#description) and [shadowed](https://mayuminishimoto.medium.com/understanding-variable-shadowing-with-javascript-58fc108c8f03) by the catch(x).

Comment: Actually this question was asked to me in an interview.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rename the `x` in `catch(x)` to `err`, because that was causing some weird overriding issues. That's why you were getting `undefined` for the second log message.

```js
(function () {
    try {
        throw new Error();
    } catch (err) {
        var x = 1,
            y = 2;
        console.log(x);
    }
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
})();
```

Result:

```
1
1
2
```

But what if we switch `var` to `const`?

```js
(function () {
    try {
        throw new Error();
    } catch (err) {
        const x = 1,
            y = 2;
        console.log(x);
    }
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
})();
```

We get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

`x` and `y` aren't defined anymore within the scope of the function. This is because `var` ignores blocks, while `const` and `let` do not.